# Change color of mesh displayed by the function CGAL::draw()

Tags: cgal

**Problem description**
I wonder if there is a way to change the color of mesh displayed by the function CGAL::draw(). I have a Surface_mesh, I want to draw it with CGAL. So I use the function CGAL::draw(), but the color of mesh is blue, which is not pretty in my view. I tried to change the code of CGAL to change the color. I found a functor called DefaultColorFunctorFaceGraph in a header file called draw_face_graoh.h, there is an annotation above the definition of DefaultColorFunctorFaceGraph, which says "// *Default color functor; user can change it to have its own face color*". I change the functor, in which I change the return value to CGAL::IO::gray(), but it doesn't work at all, the color of mesh is still blue.
So can I change the color of mesh by changing the code of CGAL? Is it necessary to change lower level code such as some codes calling OpenGL?

**Code**
Here is an example about the way I use the function draw().

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include<CGAL/draw_surface_mesh.h>
#include<CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel kernel;
typedef kernel::Point_3 point;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<point> Mesh;

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("test.off");
    Mesh mesh;
    fin >> mesh;
    CGAL::draw(mesh);
    
}
```

The file called test.off is as follws.

```
OFF
4 4 0
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0 
0 1 0
3 2 0 1
3 1 0 3
3 1 3 2
3 3 0 2
```

Here is the changed functor.

```
namespace CGAL
{

// Default color functor; user can change it to have its own face color
struct DefaultColorFunctorFaceGraph
{
  template<typename Graph>
  CGAL::IO::Color operator()(const Graph&,
                         typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::face_descriptor fh) const
  {
      if (fh == boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_face()) // use to get the mono color
        //return CGAL::IO::Color(100,125,200); // R G B between 0-255
          return CGAL::IO::gray();//Here changed

    return get_random_color(CGAL::get_default_random());
  }
};
```

**Runtime environment**
IDE: VS 2017
Solution configuration: Release x64
CGAL version: 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a struct named `Basic_viewer_qt` in a header file called `Basic_viewer_qt.h`. By changing the values of variables `m_faces_mono_color` and `m_ambient_color` in this struct, color of mesh can be changed.